# Fluent NHibernate Duplicate Columns

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am having some redundant primary key issues.

I have an Item which contains many reports. I have mapped them as shown below. I can do `Session.QueryOver(Of Item).List` and there are no extra columns generated. I can also do `Session.QueryOver(Of Report).List` and there are no extra columns generated.

However, once I try to traverse the relationship from Item to Reports, I get the SQL query shown below. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance!

**Item Mapping:**

```
Public Class ItemMapping
    Inherits ClassMap(Of Item)
    Public Sub New()
        Table("Items")
        Id(Function(x) x.ItemID)
        HasMany(Function(x) x.Reports).KeyColumn("ItemID").Inverse().Cascade.All()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Report Mapping:**

```
Public Class ReportMapping
    Inherits ClassMap(Of Report)
    Public Sub New()
        Table("Reports")
        Id(Function(x) x.ReportID)
        References(Function(x) x.Item).Column("ItemID")
        Map(Function(x) x.ReportName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**SQL Result:**

```
SELECT repor0_.ItemID as ItemID1_, 
repor0_.ReportID as Rep1_1_, 
repor0_.ReportID as Rep1_4_0_, 
repor0_.ReportName as Rep2_4_0_, 
repor0_.ItemID as ItemID4_0_ FROM dbo.Reports repor0_ WHERE repor0_.ItemID=@p0;@p0 = 1266 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [not a bug according to nhusers group](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/9fdb20d515514e82/3c8f9d8e70f694e8). Apparently NHibernate uses one column for the ID and second one for the foreign key. There are also other cases where some of the columns are sent twice. According to the thread it is not worth it to optimize the extra column away because it doesn't generate additional I/O usage and in normal cases the extra column does not cause too much network traffic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Why does it only happen sometimes? I have other relationships that don't generate additional columns. Will this cause issues with insert/update queries? I've seen some posts on here where a mapping was causing Insert/Update to fail because it was generating additional columns

Comment: @Origin The thread in nhusers group lists some cases when it happens. I've been using NHibernate in many projects and I haven't had those kind of problems (generating additional colums for insert or update). I would consider NHibernate to be very stable product.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see 'reportdate' anywhere in your presented mapping files, while it is there in your query therefore I suspect there are other mappings in your project that we currently do not see?

Comment: You are correct. My mistake for not removing it. Some of the field names are sensitive. I commented them out in the project code and tested to confirm the error is still there without the extra fields.